# Chain rule and partial derivatives in PDE problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions, chain-rule

I am a student of mathematics, currently I am taking a course of PDE's, and I found myself having some troubles with some partial derivatives, I would thanks a lot any help, here is the problem:

Prove that if $u=u(x,y,z)$ satisfy the laplace equation ($\nabla u =0$), then $$ \nabla \left[r^{-1}u(\frac{x}{r^2},\frac{y}{r^2},\frac{z}{r^2})\right]=0, \quad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ is true. To do this I take a function $$w(x,y,z)=r^{-1}u(\frac{x}{r^2},\frac{y}{r^2},\frac{z}{r^2})$$ and started to do derivates, the derivate of a product and chain rule, the problem that I am having is with the $\frac{\cdot}{r^2}$ thing, I think that it must be something like the chain rule but with an another thing that I am not seeing, I am just confused about this, thanks to everyone that wants to help me.

Comment: Laplace equation is $\nabla ^2 u=0$. By definition $\nabla^2u=\nabla \cdot (\nabla u)$ where $\nabla u$ is the gradient of u. 

$\nabla(fg)=f\nabla g + g\nabla f$.

$\nabla^2(fg)=f\nabla^2 g + 2\nabla f \cdot \nabla g +g \nabla^2 f$

Answer (score 0):

This is  the Kelvin transformation law for the Laplacian. Probably the simplest brute force method for verifying it is to expand the Laplacian $\nabla^2 f (r,\theta, \phi)=0$ in spherical coordinates, and then see what happens when you make the  transformation $r\to \tilde r=1/r$..

The other brute force method  you outlined also works .. eventually.